# Mock external dependencies in Playwright

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright

I have an application that requires logging in to a Google account before returning to my application to create an account. Automating this process proves challenging due to the presence of Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA). Is mocking the 2FA a viable option to overcome this hurdle? Is there any other option you would recommend?
Note: Unfortunately, it's not possible to disable 2FA. In CI environments, normal accounts still send codes. As for me, using a corporate account is not an option.

Additionally, I would appreciate hearing your opinion on mocking this test. I personally haven't tried mocking before, so I would like to gain a better understanding. Here are the steps involved:

a) Login to the application.

b) Navigate to the connect page.

c) Click on the "connect" button, which redirects the user to the Google sign-in page.

d) Once successfully logged in, an object is created within the application.

e) After this occurs, users can access their Google data within the app, and they receive notifications whenever there are changes in the Google data.

If I were to explore mocking, how would it work in my case? Is it possible to simulate steps d and e?